# How to link already stored data to users in Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I am creating an application that would allow users to access data on their phones. Examples would be progress scores/test results.

I can upload the data to Firebase with an email address as the user link.

Is there a way that I can link this already loaded data to a user (with the same email address) once they have registered? Ideally using the email address in a rule to search up that data and use that reference point in the app.

Ideally I would like to pre-upload the users in bulk, but I know that Firebase only allows one user to be added at a time.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

After a user sign in to the app through the Firebase auth you can get its email through this call:

```
FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getEmail()
```

If you want to import data into your database, you should first make a json out of your data (list of users by email) and then use [Firebase-Import](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-import) to put it in your datastore.

Comment: At the moment I am not concerned with accessing the user data that they sign in with. As I can used Email/Password Authentication on Firebase.

What I am working with is that I have data I would like to upload to the database that is for all the users (I have a finite list of users for the app), and attach that data to each of the users in question. Or use their login info to automatically read that set record of data.